# Automapper in MVC Core 2.0 services.AddAutoMapper() behavior

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, automapping

I have a solution like this:

```
MVC Core 2.0 application <-> Business Class library <-> Domain class library
(ViewModel)    <- P1 ->      (Dto)         <-P2->       (Domain entity)
```

I created Automapper profiles in each MVC and Business projects for mapping ViewModel<->Dto (P1) and Dto<->Domain entity (P2). P1 profile&map is in MVC project, P2 profile&map is in Business library.

I then made a xUnit test project which creates a Dto object and sends it to a Business Service, inside the unit test on init I call:

```
Business.App.AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
```

And this unit test works exactly as expected.

I then do the same (I even copy/pasted code from Unit test) in the MVC controller and I get an error **in mapping Dto to Domain entity**:

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below...
```

I configured Automapper maps in startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

If I understand correctly this is supposed to traverse all assemblies for classes inheriting Profile and adding them to configuration.

Example map:

```
public class StrankaMap : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName => nameof(StrankaMap);

    public StrankaMap()
    {
        CreateMap<SomeDto, SomeDomainEntity>().ReverseMap()
        CreateMap<AnotherDto, AnotherDomainEntity>().ReverseMap()
    }
}
```

I don't know what is the cause of this error if my unit test works but not from MVC app - I even copied the code from unit test to MVC controller and ran that. I'm suspecting an error in configuration. Do I assume correctly that inside Startup.cs adding services.AddAutoMapper(); is enough for this to work?

**Solution** (edit)

Apparently I misunderstood that the service.AddAutoMapper() will traverse all assemblies and search for Profile inherited classes. There might be a better solution but I used the one below, with the help of a hint from the comment @LucianBargaoanu.

I solved it like this:

```
// Startup.cs

services.AddAutoMapper(
    typeof(Business.App.AutoMapperConfiguration),
    typeof(MvcApp.Infrastructure.Configuration.AutoMapperConfiguration));


//And the AutoMapperConfiguration class:

namespace MvcApp.Infrastructure.Configuration
{
    using AutoMapper;

    public class AutoMapperConfiguration
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.AddProfile<Models.Mapping.StrankaMap>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it like [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thank you, it led me to the solution. Apparently service.AddAutoMapper() doesn't traverse _all_ assemblies so my Business profile&map wasn't getting set. If you post as an answer I can accept it. I will update my question with the solution.

Comment: It's ok :) Just post the solution.

Comment: @Iztoksson Post the solution as a self answer. That way you can get rewarded from those who find the solution helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I misunderstood that the service.AddAutoMapper() will traverse all assemblies and search for Profile inherited classes. There might be a better solution but I used the one below, with the help of a hint from the comment @LucianBargaoanu.

I solved it like this:

```
// Startup.cs

services.AddAutoMapper(
    typeof(Business.App.AutoMapperConfiguration),
    typeof(MvcApp.Infrastructure.Configuration.AutoMapperConfiguration));


//And the AutoMapperConfiguration class:

namespace MvcApp.Infrastructure.Configuration
{
    using AutoMapper;

    public class AutoMapperConfiguration
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.AddProfile<Models.Mapping.StrankaMap>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```